# JQuery - Add click event to multiple elements

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have the following:

```
$('#applicationsGrid tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var formattedData = dosomething();
    $(this).parent('tr').after(formattedData);
});

$('#applicationsGrid tbody').on('click', 'td.child-details-control', function () {
    var formattedData = dosomething();
    $(this).parent('tr').after(formattedData);
});

$('#applicationsGrid tbody').on('click', 'td.grand-child-details-control', function () {
    var formattedData = dosomething();
    $(this).parent('tr').after(formattedData);
});
```

How can I combine all the "on" events into one click event that would take care of clicking on 'td.details-control', 'td.child-details-control', 'td.grand-child-details-control', so I can reduce duplicate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)** in jquery

```
$('#applicationsGrid tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control,td.child-details-control,td.grand-child-details-control', function () {
      var formattedData = dosomething();
      $(this).parent('tr').after(formattedData);
});
```

[**Learn Multiple selector**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Just you can concatenate with multiselector

```
$('#applicationsGrid tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control,td.child-details-control,td.grand-child-details-control', function () {
              var formattedData = dosomething();
              $(this).parent('tr').after(formattedData);
            });
```

OR use *[end with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)* ,in your case all class value is ended with **details-control**,

```
  $('#applicationsGrid tbody').on('click', ,'td[class$=details-control]', function () {
              var formattedData = dosomething();
              $(this).parent('tr').after(formattedData);
            });
```